# Find which extension is using storage

Tags: firefox-extensions, local-storage

My Firefox profile is getting quite big, so I had a look at where the space is being used. Most of it (>750MiB!) is in `storage/default/moz-extension+++{redacted-uuid}^userContextId={redacted-number}`. How can I find out what extension this is and control its use of storage? I only have a few extensions installed and can't think of any reason for any of them to be using that much space.

The addons I'm using are:

- [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/)
- [Close Tab History Button](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/close-tab-history-button/)
- [Conset-O-Matic](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/consent-o-matic/)
- [Tree Style Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/)
- [Unload Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/close-tab-history-button/)

If I knew which addon was using the space I'd be happy to report this to the author and/or just delete the data (maybe, depends on what I'd be giving up).

The other usage of the `storage/default` folder seems to be for per-domain web storage, which I know can be cleared via Firefox's Preferences. However that UI doesn't seem to offer an equivalent for addons.

Is there some way to find the UUIDs of my installed extensions? Or another way to work out which extensions is writing this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spotted from one of the `.metadata-v2` files within the extension's storage directory that the `moz-extension+++{redacted-uuid}` was similar to `moz-extension://{redacted-uuid}` mentioned there.

Visiting that url within Firefox reveals which extension this is -- in the site information block.

Turns out that it's Adblock Plus which is using all the space.

Comment: on a side note, AdBlock Plus keeps a list of "acceptable ads", which you can get on, if you pay the company behind ABP money. Maybe time to switch adblocker? uBlock Origin (the full name is important) has always worked quite well for me, and it did at no point use more than maybe 10 MB of local storage.